# Sort objects of objects by nested property

Tags: javascript, sorting, object

I have an object that looks like the one below.  How can I sort something like this based on a common property within nested object.  The output I expect is for player2 to come first based on the higher score.

My challenge is in accessing the property of each object to sort.

Here is what I had in mind and tried but it didn't do the sorting.

```
Object.keys(data).sort(function(p1, p2){
    return p1.score - p2.score;
}).forEach(function(key) {
    var value = data[key];
    delete data[key];
    data[key] = value;
});
```

My data

```
var data =
    { 
      player1:
       { score: 4,
         cards: 6 },
      player2:
       { score: 6,
         cards: 4} 
    }
```

Comment: The properties of a JavaScript object are unordered. If you want values in a specific order, you need to put them in an array.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to sort the data with the object, not with a key's property and then it has to be reverted, because you need a descending sort.

```
return data[b].score - data[a].score;
//     ^^^^^^^         ^^^^^^^        object
//          ^               ^         descending
```

I suggest to use an empty object and insert the properties by the ordered keys.

```js
var data = { player1: { score: 4, cards: 6 }, player2: { score: 6, cards: 4 } },
    sorted = {};

Object
    .keys(data).sort(function(a, b){
        return data[b].score - data[a].score;
    })
    .forEach(function(key) {
        sorted[key] = data[key];
    });

console.log(sorted);
```

Comment: if you write properties using sorted[key] then you get an object with the same [key]:[value] pairs as the original data... You cannot depend on this write order. (afaik it depends on your javascript engines' implementation and it decides on the order it reads them back out when you use Object.keys or Reflect.ownProps.)

Answer (score 4):

Here is one line functional approach using `Object.entries()`, `Array.prototype.sort()` and `Object.fromEntries` method. Before sorting you need to make the object an array by using `Object.entries()` method. It returns array of key-value pair of the given object. Then sort the array in descending order by the score. At last, use `Object.fromEntries()` method to transform the key-value pair into an object.

```js
const data = {
  player1: { score: 4, cards: 6 },
  player2: { score: 6, cards: 4 },
};

const ret = Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(data).sort((x, y) => y[1].score - x[1].score)
);
console.log(ret);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't sort an object. You should convert your object to an array and then sort it.

```js
var data =
    { 
      player1:
       { score: 4,
         cards: 6 },
      player2:
       { score: 6,
         cards: 4} 
    }

var array = $.map(data, function(value, index) {
    value.key = index;
    return value;
});

var sortedData = array.sort(function(p1, p2){
    return p2.score - p1.score;
});
console.log(sortedData);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You should state that jQuery is a requirement here. OP didn't ask for it.