# Sort object keys by property value

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, ecmascript-6

I have an object that contains multiple entries/keys. Each key maps to an array that contains one or multiple entries. My goal is to sort the keys in obj by its filterGroupDisplayOrder found in the first position and return them in their own array. Example:

**Desired Result**

```
['apple', 'kiwi', 'watermelon', 'orange', 'blueberry', 'grape'] // keys sorted by filterGroupDisplayOrder 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60
```

**Sample Object**

```
const obj = {
    "apple": [
        {
            "filterGroupId": "apple",
            "filterGroupLabelKey": "Apple",
            "filterGroupDisplayOrder": 10,
        }
    ],
    "orange": [
        {
            "filterGroupId": "orange",
            "filterGroupLabelKey": "Orange",
            "filterGroupDisplayOrder": 40
        }
    ],
    "grape": [
        {
            "filterGroupId": "grape",
            "filterGroupLabelKey": "Grape",
            "filterGroupDisplayOrder": 60
        }
    ]
    "kiwi": [
        {
            "filterGroupId": "kiwi",
            "filterGroupLabelKey": "Kiwi",
            "filterGroupDisplayOrder": 20
        }
    ],
    "watermelon": [
        {
            "filterGroupId": "watermelon",
            "filterGroupLabelKey": "Watermelon",
            "filterGroupDisplayOrder": 30
        }
    ],
    "blueberry": [
        {
            "filterGroupId": "blueberry",
            "filterGroupLabelKey": "Blueberry",
            "filterGroupDisplayOrder": 50
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: what have you tried to achieve this? Are you having difficulty getting an array of all keys, or are you having difficulty in sorting that array in the way you describe?

Comment: I am having trouble sorting by filterGroupDisplayOrder ... I have looked into using Object.keys and Object.entries

Comment: Why do the object properties contain arrays? Would it ever contain two values, and what would the desired outcome be if it did?

Comment: The object properties contain arrays because there will be multiple entries. For the sake of this example, I only returned one. But, each of the objects in the array will have same filterGroupDisplayOrder, filterGroupId and filterGroupLabelKey.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sort objects of objects by nested property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48409741/sort-objects-of-objects-by-nested-property) Just instead of `blah.score`, you'd use `blah[0].filterGroupDisplayOrder`.

Comment: @HereticMonkey the output desired is a sorted array of keys, not an object with sorted keys. (I did the same mistake).

Comment: Is `filterGroupId` always the same as the key?

Comment: @VLAZ And apparently the cognitive leap to remove the part that turns the array back to an object is a leap too far...

Comment: @HereticMonkey not really. I just don't think it's an accurate dupe in this case. It's more of a "how do I sort this array based on another array" type of thing rather than "sort the keys in this object and then extract them as an array". The latter can fail if there is any non-negative integer key. https://jsbin.com/keciceh/edit?js,console

Answer (score 2):

You can get the list of keys with `Object.keys()`, then sort it by using the object's filterGroupDisplayValues.  (Since you said the display order will always be the same for each top-level key, I just used the first one from each array here.)

```js
const obj = { "apple": [{ "filterGroupId": "apple", "filterGroupLabelKey": "Apple", "filterGroupDisplayOrder": 10, }], "orange": [{ "filterGroupId": "orange", "filterGroupLabelKey": "Orange", "filterGroupDisplayOrder": 40 }], "grape": [{ "filterGroupId": "grape", "filterGroupLabelKey": "Grape", "filterGroupDisplayOrder": 60 }], "kiwi": [{ "filterGroupId": "kiwi", "filterGroupLabelKey": "Kiwi", "filterGroupDisplayOrder": 20 }], "watermelon": [{ "filterGroupId": "watermelon", "filterGroupLabelKey": "Watermelon", "filterGroupDisplayOrder": 30 }], "blueberry": [{ "filterGroupId": "blueberry", "filterGroupLabelKey": "Blueberry", "filterGroupDisplayOrder": 50 }] }

const output = Object.keys(obj).sort((a, b) => {
  return obj[a][0].filterGroupDisplayOrder - obj[b][0].filterGroupDisplayOrder
})
console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try running this:

```js
Object.entries(obj).sort((a, b) => {return a[1][0].filterGroupDisplayOrder - b[1][0].filterGroupDisplayOrder}).map(e => e[0]);
```

Comment: OP needs only the keys.

Answer (score 0):

- Create a nested array out of the object `obj` using `Object.entries`.
- Sort this nested array by `filterGroupDisplayOrder` using `Array#sort`.
- Extract out the keys using `Array#map`.

```js
const 
  obj={apple:[{filterGroupId:"apple",filterGroupLabelKey:"Apple",filterGroupDisplayOrder:10}],orange:[{filterGroupId:"orange",filterGroupLabelKey:"Orange",filterGroupDisplayOrder:40}],grape:[{filterGroupId:"grape",filterGroupLabelKey:"Grape",filterGroupDisplayOrder:60}],kiwi:[{filterGroupId:"kiwi",filterGroupLabelKey:"Kiwi",filterGroupDisplayOrder:20}],watermelon:[{filterGroupId:"watermelon",filterGroupLabelKey:"Watermelon",filterGroupDisplayOrder:30}],blueberry:[{filterGroupId:"blueberry",filterGroupLabelKey:"Blueberry",filterGroupDisplayOrder:50}]},
      
  res = Object.entries(obj)
    .sort(([, [a]], [, [b]]) => {
      return a.filterGroupDisplayOrder - b.filterGroupDisplayOrder;
    })
    .map(([k]) => k);

console.log(res);
```

Comment: `.map(([k, v]) => k);` -> `.map(([k]) => k);` it's shorter, you don't need to destructure both items in the entry :P

Comment: Also `.sort((a, b)` can be  `.sort(([,[a]], [,[b]])` and then you can use `a.filterGroupDisplayOrder - b.filterGroupDisplayOrder` in the body. But it's just on the verge of being too much destructuring for my taste.

Comment: @VLAZ `.sort(([, [a]], [, [b]])` I did this.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const obj={apple:[{filterGroupId:"apple",filterGroupLabelKey:"Apple",filterGroupDisplayOrder:10}],orange:[{filterGroupId:"orange",filterGroupLabelKey:"Orange",filterGroupDisplayOrder:40}],grape:[{filterGroupId:"grape",filterGroupLabelKey:"Grape",filterGroupDisplayOrder:60}],kiwi:[{filterGroupId:"kiwi",filterGroupLabelKey:"Kiwi",filterGroupDisplayOrder:20}],watermelon:[{filterGroupId:"watermelon",filterGroupLabelKey:"Watermelon",filterGroupDisplayOrder:30}],blueberry:[{filterGroupId:"blueberry",filterGroupLabelKey:"Blueberry",filterGroupDisplayOrder:50}]};

const res = Object.values(obj)
                .map(v => v[0])
                .sort((a,b) => a.filterGroupDisplayOrder - b.filterGroupDisplayOrder)
                .map(e => e.filterGroupId)

console.log(res)
```